# jQuery mobile popup opens in new window

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I am trying to do a popup in my mobile app. My code is this:

```
<a id="options" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" href="#optionsPopup" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true"></a>

<div data-role="popup" id="optionsPopup" data-overlay-theme="a" style="padding-top: 40px">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="data-theme:a">
        <li><a href="#" id="go">Go to</a>
            <input name="goInput" type="hidden" data-role="datebox" id="goInput" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}' />
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="compare">Compare</a>
            <input name="compareInput" type="hidden" data-role="datebox" id="compareInput" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}' />
        </li>
        <li><a onclick="goToday()" >Today</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click in #options the popup opens but not in an popup but in a new window!

Does anyone has any idea why is this happening??

Comment: have you tried it in multiple browsers?  Some browsers have a setting to open popups in new tabs.

Comment: For the time being I am trying it in firefox and google chrome. In my mobile with dolphin browser and Android browser is not working either!

Comment: Seems to be working here correctly http://jsfiddle.net/XJDGe/ something else must be happening that you are not showing in your example.

Comment: For me it's not working. It appears but not in a popup! it replaces the page content with the popup content!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you perhaps mean to use `data-rel="dialog"` instead of `data-rel="popup"`?

If so, you can see more about the dialog documentation [**here**](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html).

Updating the fiddle from the comments would get you [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/XJDGe/1/).

Comment: I was trying to do a popup, but I don't know why is not working! But dialog addapts my needs!! thx!!!